# How to use operator like geater than, less than etc in sorry-cypress graphql api

Tags: graphql, sorrycypress

I wanted to filter out specific runs based on `createdAt` property on sorry-cypress. I was able to add the exact match via parameter. I could not figure out how to give a date range filter in the sorry-cypress graphql query. A greater than and less than operator will help. I could not find any documentation on it too. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry-Cypress has some grapql reference hidden in their repo - https://github.com/sorry-cypress/sorry-cypress/blob/master/packages/api/src/schema/schema.graphql

There you can find `input Filters` that has `like` field in it, so we can apply the following:

```
query dateSelectionQuery {
    runs(
        filters: [
            {
                key: "createdAt"
                like: "2023-08"
            }
        ]
    ) {
        runId
    }
}
```

This query will output all run IDs for August. You can play around with this `like` field and get an appropriate pattern.